# Reusable templates and methods?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I wish to wrap different types of input with a label and an error message, so far I have come up with this solution, using slots:

Input Text Component: (but there are also others for select, checkbox etc)

```
<form-input>
    <input type="text" @click="doSomething">  //could be select, checkboxes etc. slotted in
</form-input>
```

Generic Form Input Component:

```
<div>
    <label v-text="label"></label>
    <slot></slot> //where each input is placed
    <p v-if="hasError">This {{ this.name }} has an error!</p>
</div>
```

On `Input Text Component` I also use a mixin that handles all the errors and other form bits, I need to declare this in every different input type, select, checkbox etc.

Is there an easier way to achieve this, I want to:

1. Wrap various inputs with errors and labels.
2. Use the same functionality from a mixin (or declared as something else) for every component but not repeat the declaration - I cannot add it on the generic form input component as it is referenced in the data in the parent to be slotted in.

Comment: Could you share more code please ? how exactly do you use your mixin, and why can't you use it in the Generic Form Component already ?